# How to get the stack trace from errors in a FireFox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, stack-trace, chromebug

Is there a convenient way to do this for my extension? I know I can use FireBug to get traces for exceptions which happen in content, but I don't think it works for chrome (does it?). I couldn't get ChromeBug to work when I last tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried checking the "Show Chrome Errors" and "Show Stack Trace with Errors" options in the Console menu of Firebug 1.5?  (They might be in earlier versions too.)  If your extension is for Firebug itself, this post on [Firebug tracing](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/tracing-console-for-firebug/) should be helpful.